# Need help in mysql update query

Tags: mysql

Guys I am stuck on a MySql query. Following is my query to `SELECT` data from my database. I am stuck on `Update` query to update the `Price`.

`Select Query`

```
SELECT p.id, p.post_title, m.meta_key as Type, m.meta_value as SKU ,k.meta_value as price 
FROM wp8k_posts p 
INNER JOIN wp8k_postmeta m ON p.id=m.post_id 
AND m.meta_key='_sku'
INNER JOIN wp8k_postmeta k ON p.id=k.post_id
AND k.meta_key='_sale_price'
where m.meta_value= 'GLC-LH-SM'
```

`Update Query`

```
Update wp8k_postmeta k
INNER JOIN wp8k_posts p ON p.id=m.post_id 
AND m.meta_key='_sku'
INNER JOIN wp8k_postmeta k ON p.id=k.post_id 
AND k.meta_key='_sale_price'
set k.meta_key = 90
where m.meta_value= 'GLC-LH-SM'
```

can anyone help please.

Comment: And what exectly is the Problem?

Comment: the update query is not working at all

Comment: What happens when you try your update query? Do you get a database error or are the wrong rows being updated?

Comment: When you say that it is "not working at all", is it throwing an error message or is it just not updating any rows?

Comment: its says `#1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'k'`

Comment: @FahadBinZafar `is not working at all` is not precise. Can you Show an exaple.

Comment: Obviously you are updating `wp8k_postmeta k` and joining same table (`INNER JOIN wp8k_postmeta k`) with same alias so either remove this join or change second alias to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use unique aliasses for all tables:

```
Update wp8k_postmeta k 
INNER JOIN wp8k_posts p  ON p.id=k.post_id AND k.meta_key='_sale_price'
INNER JOIN wp8k_postmeta m ON p.id=m.post_id AND m.meta_key='_sku'
set k.meta_key = 90
where m.meta_value= 'GLC-LH-SM'
```

Comment: its saying `#1054 - Unknown column 'm.meta_value' in 'where clause'`

Comment: it worked. but have to change the `set k.meta_key = 90` to `set k.meta_value = 90`

Comment: @FahadBinZafar ok that was not visible in your question